# Does "subject" still apply to inhabitants of monarchies nowadays?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

When it comes to the following meaning of word **subject** (from [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/subject)):

> a person who lives in or who has the right to live in a particular country, especially a country with a king or queen

Although the definition is broad and seems like a synonym for **citizen**, I wonder if it is correct to use **subject** to refer to common citizens of countries like England or Japan nowadays.

Or does the word imply some degree of subjugation, being more suitable to refer to people of older colonial times (like British subjects living in colonial India)?

Thanks!

Comment: Besides meaning "one owing allegiance to a monarch or other supreme ruler" it is also means "a person who is the focus of scientific or medical attention or experiment." Either way, it is not a complimentary way to talk about people, unless you are a supreme ruler, or a mad scientist.

Comment: You _can_, but _should_ you? No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_subject

I remember that the passport I had as a child in the 1960s called me a British subject, but *citizen* is preferred nowadays.